# Best way to parallelize multi-table function in Python (using Pandas)

Tags: pandas, function, parallel-processing, dask

I have this function below that iterates through every row of a data frame (using pandas apply) and determines what values are valid from a prediction-probability matrix (L2) by referencing another data frame (GST) to obtain the valid values for a given row. The function just returns the row back with the maximum valid probability assigned to the previously blank value for that row (Predicted Level 2) in the data frame passed to the function (test_x2)

Not a terribly complex function and it works fine on smaller datasets but when I scale to like 3-5 million records, it starts to take way too long. I tried using the multiprocessing module as well as dask/numba but nothing was able to improve the runtime (not sure if this is just due to the fact the function is not vectorizable).

My question is two fold:

1) Is there a better way to write this? (I'm guessing there is)

2) If not, what parallel computing strategies could work with this type of function? I've already tried a number of different python options but I'm just leaning more towards running the larger datasets on totally separate machines at this point. Feel free to provide any suggested code to parallelize something like this. Thanks in advance for any guidance provided.

```
l2 = MNB.predict_proba(test_x)
l2_classes = MNB.classes_
L2 = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns = MNB.classes_)
test_x2["Predicted Level 2"] = ""

def predict_2(row):
    s = row["Predicted Level 1"]
    s = GST.loc[s,:]
    s.reset_index(inplace = True)
    Valid_Level2s = s["GST Level 2"].tolist()
    p2 = L2.ix[row.name, Valid_Level2s]
    max2 = p2.idxmax(axis = 1)
    output = row["Predicted Level 2"] = max2
    return row

test_x2 = test_x2.apply(predict_2, axis = 1)
```

Comment: can you add some input data to work on

Comment: As mentioned, sample data would help. If I understand the code correctly,  a pandas `join` may speed things up.